# How to declare Database Mappings with @OneToMany and @ManyToOne annotations using Spring-JPA and Hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

Let's say I had the following business model:

*Users have up to n Vehicles*.

This is my **DAO** / **Domain** Class for Users:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="USER")
public @Data class User extends AbstractPersistable<Long> {
    @OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.PERSIST, mappedBy="owner")
    private Set<Vehicle> vehicles = new HashSet<Vehicle>();
}
```

And this the Class for Vehicle:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="VEHICLE")
public @Data class Vehicle extends AbstractPersistable<Long> {
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
    User owner;
}
```

I want to be able to save a new Vehicle for a new User like this:

```
User user = new User();
user.setName("Fred"); // other setters omitted

Vehicle vehicle = new Vehicle();
vehicle.setEngine("..."); // other setters omitted 

user.getVehicles().add(vehicle);
userService.saveUser(user);
```

**userService.saveUser()** is a Service Layer method being annotated as *@Transactional* and calling userRepository.save(user); (see at the bottom for an excerpt from the Repository class)

---

***Now a couple of questions since my solution isn't working as expected:***

**1.** Is that even possible to just save the user object and have the Vehicle-Set inside the user object automatically be persisted?
**2.** Is this the best practice? I know User is the owning entity. I want all vehicles of a user to be removed when a user is removed.
**3.** Or do I always have to do something like *vehicle.setOwner(user);*?
**4.** What's an optimal solution for this from your point of view?

I read a whole lot about owning entities and JoinColumn/mappedBy. Yet now I am more confused than before.

---

Additionally, that's an excerpt from my UserRepository:

```
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.myproject.domains.User;

public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> { 
User findByLoginName(String loginName); 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You certainly need to set the reference of `User` in your `Vehicle` entity's object, otherwise Hibernate won't recognize the relation.

Also I would recommend using `@OneToMany` with

- `cascade=CascadeType.ALL` for proper cascade operations (note, that usually you don't touch `Vehicle` separatelly from `User` at all)
- `fetch = FetchType.EAGER` to avoid `LazyInitializationException` (note, that you can't have more then 1 EAGER relation in your JPA configuration)
- `orphanRemoval = true` for cleaning up of "unnecessary" vehicles after user's update

Comment: Can you please explain what you mean by *can't have more than 1 EAGER relation*? My user class has actually 4 *Sets* and thus 4 OneToMany relations with fetch type **EAGER**. And I don't get errors.

Comment: Please see: http://www.jroller.com/eyallupu/entry/hibernate_exception_simultaneously_fetch_multiple It's quite popular error within the Hibernate, so the most common workaround is to avoid EAGER fetches. BTW, it's quite interesting why it's working for you, because in my current project 2 EAGER entities within the class are not working (throws `MultipleBagFetchException: cannot simultaneously fetch multiple bags`)

Comment: It is working for now but without EAGER I had to use LAZY and will run into *no session* errors. Thanks for your help so far and pointing the EAGER problem out. I created a [new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15094109/easiest-way-to-add-vehicle-to-user-with-jpa-hibernate-using-spring) regarding the possibility to omit setOwner() in the *Many* part of the OneToMany relation (which effectively sets the user, just called it owner).

Comment: n1ckolas: Reading your link I figured I don't get the `MultipleBagFetchException` because I use a `Set` instead of a `List`.

Answer (score 0):

`CascadeType.PERSIST` persists `vehicles` set if there is only a persist situation.

I recommend you to use `CascadeType.ALL`. Thus `vehicles` will be removed when you remove the user, as well as, vehicles will be updated/persisted if you update/persist the user.

*vehicle.setOwner(user)* is necessary if you want to access *user* from a *vehicle*.

Comment: Alright, I set it to CascadeType.ALL.
I don't need to access *user* from *vehicle*. I just need to get all vehicles when having a *user id*. Have a look at my 4 questions, I am really new to this topic and need a few pointers.

Comment: You can also use `fetch = FetchType.LAZY`, which enables lazy-loading for the set. I believe that hibernate docs is a good place to start: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.6/reference/en-US/html/collections.html