# Easiest way to add Vehicle to User with JPA/Hibernate using Spring

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

Let's say I had this in my **UserDAO** class:

```
@OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy="owner", fetch=FetchType.EAGER,         orphanRemoval=true)
private Set<Vehicle> vehicles = new HashSet<Vehicle>();
```

Is this the recommended way to add a new vehicle to a User:

```
User user = userService.findByLoginName("MartinL");
Vehicle newVehicle = new Vehicle();
newVehicle.set(...) // setters omitted
newVehicle.setOwner(user)  // is this needed in any case?
user.getVehicles().add(newVehicle) // add the new vehicle to the Set in User class
userService.save(user); // persist the modified user object to database
```

Is this the *best practice* or do I miss on anything?

Answer (score 3):

I prefer the direct approach of saving the `newVehicle` (after setting the `owner` attribute, of course).

Advantages:

1) Your approach will force the framework to check all the attributes of user and write them back at the DB, and will also write again all of the vehicles.

2) It is more readable, in the sense that it makes more clear that your intent is just to add a new vehicle

3) If you are doing this change, you may not even need to retrieve the `user` object from database, if you use [`EntityManager.getReference()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#getReference%28java.lang.Class,%20java.lang.Object%29)

Answer (score 3):

You normally want to manage bidirectional associations from the (JPA defined) dependent side of the relationship, and within the dependent class. Pseudocode:

```
class User {
    private Set<Vehicle> vehicles;

    public void addVehicle(Vehicle vehicle) {
        if(vehicle == null) return;

        vehicle.setOwner(this);
        vehicles.add(vehicle);
    }

    public void removeVehicle(Vehicle vehicle) {
        if(vehicle == null) return;

        if(vehicles.remove(vehicle)) {
            vehicle.setOwner(null);
        }
    }
}
```

Managing the relationship outside of the entities leads to bugs and duplicated code.

Comment: @JBNizet - true. Even though I always hated that inverted, db-oriented terminology. Will update the answer.

Comment: I have a `UserService` class which calls the persistance methods in a `UserRepository` class (inheriting from `JpaRepository`). My `User` class is a separate class inside a .domains package. Since I am new to java: When my business logic is inside the **Service** and I have separate Data classes, how is your advice  applicable to this scenario? Or in other words: How do I pass my User object to my Service class?

Comment: @MartinLundberg - I think thats an unrelated (and somewhat vague) question. It would probably be best if you made another SO post, with code clearly illustrating what you're trying to do.